# How to go beyond callback programming?

Tags: design-patterns, oop, callback

I've noticed that a big part of my code is built around callbacks. Is this considered a "design flaw"? Are there better design patterns that I should follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not bad, it's just the only way to do functional programming in non-functional languages.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you could see the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) as something that could be used akin to callbacks. Have you checked them out?

In the book [Pragmatic Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X), they mention the example of a person waiting to be boarded on a flight. Instead of that person asking the check-in desk constantly whether it's okay for her to go on board (polling), the check-in desk announces publicly to all those interested when the flight is ready.

A pseudocode for this example might look something like this:

```
class Clerk implements CheckInNotifyer {
  BunchOfObservers observers = new Bunch();

  public void addObserver(CheckInObserver observer) {
    observers.add(observer);
  }

  private void notifyListeners() {
    observers.all.notifyCheckIn(new CheckInEvent());
  }
}

class Passenger implements CheckInObserver {
  public void notifyCheckIn(CheckInEvent event) {
    event.getPlane().board();
  }
}

class WaitingArea {
  public init() {
    Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
    Clerk clerk = new Clerk();

    clerk.addObserver(passenger);
  }
}
```

Comment: Whether the observer pattern can be meaningfully termed a management structure for callbacks is left as an exercise for the interested student. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's also known as [event-driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).

Answer (score 3):

Another option that works especially well when you have a number of procedures with callbacks going at once is to use WaitHandles.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  For Javascript, I prefer the observer pattern for anything that can actually be aware of a fired event - mainly because you can register and manage multiple observers.  But for something like an AJAX call, wrapping it in a closure and including the callback method seems like the cleanest approach.

Answer (score -1):

In an object oriented language I find polymorphism a much 'cleaner' (no casting and no messy function type declarations) and a more object oriented method (deriving from an interface) to achieve the functionallity provided by callbacks.

Comment: -1 the answer makes no sense. Callbacks don't lead to (unnecessary) casting.